# How can i remove the item already selected from the dropdown list

Tags: angularjs

I have created a plunker for this code, when I add an item row and select from the list of items, I don't wannt that item to be in the list again when i add another row of items to select from. Check the plunker i created, I really don't know how to go about it https://plnkr.co/edit/u5cSwJqCwL5clpcWGuhN

```
$scope.items = [];
    $scope.filter = {};
    $scope.addItem = function () {
        if ($scope.items === null) {
            $scope.items = [{}];
            return;
            }
        $scope.items.push({});
        };
    $scope.removeItem = function (index) {
    $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
        calculateTotal();

    };
```

Comment: Provide your code in your question as well, please.

Comment: Item list is empty in your plunker.

Comment: You need to add item, click on the add item button

Answer (score 2):

You need to use filter based on function like this:

```
ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in laundryitems|filter: myfilter(item)"
```

and:

```
$scope.usedItemsArray=[];
$scope.myfilter=function(value){
    return function(){
    return ($scope.usedItemsArray.indexOf(value)<0);//not found
    }
};
```

finally you need to add selected items to usedItemsArray and remove them when unselected.

Comment: I'll appreciate if you can help me update my plunker from the link @mjkhonline, thanks